# Haven't got Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll but

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, ssis

I am trying to write a .NET program so I can execute a Dts pacakge but I cannot find the *Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll* reference so I can then use the namespace Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.

However I have SQL Server 2008 Developer edition installed on my development machine along with Visual Studio 2008 and 2010. Therefore it should be there, What have I missed?

Many thanks

Mike

Answer (score 24, accepted):

<strike>In References, browse to this directory:</strike>

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\90\SDK\Assemblies

hopefully you'll find it there.

The above was for SQL Server 2005.  It should be located in your GAC.  Have a look in:

> C:\Windows\assembly

for the DLL as Visual Studio won't list all of the DLLs so you'll have to browse to it.

Comment: This helped me as well. I had to go down to C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS

Comment: If when you go to the C:\Windows\assembly\ folder you don't have access to the GAC_MSIL folder you need to edit the registry so the folder becomes available.  This link will show you how to do it:  [http://geekswithblogs.net/khanna/archive/2004/11/01/14150.aspx](http://geekswithblogs.net/khanna/archive/2004/11/01/14150.aspx)

Comment: When I select the file and click OK the folder just refreshes from the `Add Reference` window.

Answer (score 16):

For Windows 7 "Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS" can be found in following path

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS\"

Comment: I found it here in 8.1 also.

Comment: It's there for Windows 10 too.

Answer (score 5):

For SQL 2005

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS.dll`

For SQL 2008

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS.dll`

If you still can't find the Assembly, make sure you've installed the **Client Tools SDK.**

Comment: where is the link to download the SDK

Answer (score 5):

One more option to try if above given solution does not work.

Add a script Task to SSIS ControlFlow Panel. Double click to configure.
Click on Edit Script... Script page will open as project in Visual Studio. 
Find the reference Folder under the project. 
Here Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll will be added for you by default. 
Click on the Dll and go to property window. 
Copy the path. 
This worked for me after a trial and error. I am using VS Data Tools trial version.

Answer (score 2):

For dotnet Framework 4.0
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS\v4.0_11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91